# SMS Message not received by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to write a broadcast receiver to process received SMS, and launch an alert dialog to receive inputs from a user. This broadcast receiver is expected to work when the main application (MainActivity) is closed (by swiping).

Based on the input of user, the receiver adds some content to a file in the android file system after asking user permission through an alert. I noticed that the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver is not being called at all

1. I am obtaining permissions from user using requestPermissions in MainActivity
2. I am starting a service named ServiceCommunicator
3. ServiceCommunicator registers the receiver for listening to SMS
4. Receiver displays an alert message

I have also tried without having ServiceCommunicator (Receiver is registered in MainActivity itself)

In both cases above, the receiver's onCreate is not fired. The receiver is listed in the adb shell command:

adb shell cmd package query-receivers --brief -a android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

MainActivity has the following as part of the onCreate method:

```java
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
        android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
};

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceCommunicator.class);
startService(serviceIntent);

...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for SMS receive permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SMS can't be received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for SMS send permissions",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS can't be sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

ServiceCommunicator has the following:

```java
receiverIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
receiverIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

// Register SMS event receiver

registerReceiver(myReceiver, receiverIntentFilter);
```

Receiver has the following in the onReceive:

```java
if (intent.getAction() == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")
{

...

Intent alertDialogIntent = new Intent(context, AlertDialogActivity.class);
                        alertDialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alertDialogIntent.putExtra("ALERT_MSG", alertMsg);
alertDialogIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "\n" + msg);
context.startActivity(alertDialogIntent);

}
```

AlertDialogActivity has the following:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder
        .setTitle("Add information to system?")
        .setMessage(alertMsg)
...
```

Manifest.xml has the following. Updated the file (sorry, had missed it earlier):

```java
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

        <receiver android:priority="2147483647" android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:process="com.example.rtien.ServiceCommunicator" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:stopWithTask="false" android:name="com.example.rtien.ServiceCommunicator" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Expected result: When the MainActivity is closed, the receiver should run in background. The onReceive method in the receiver should be fired. The alert message should be shown, and the data added to the file

Observed result: The receiver's onReceive is fired when the MainActivity is alive, but not when it is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because when you swipe an application from recents tray it closes the application completely in many devices resulting in closing of your service also and unregistering your broadcast receiver.

Try this code for avoiding of killing down your service and make sure you have the auto-start permission & all other permissions

Add it in your service

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        try {
            Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
            restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
            PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                        getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I had missed to include the 3 lines for permissions in my first edit. The permissions were given in manifest and also asked programmatically

Comment: i have updated my answer to add this code in your service and make sure you give auto start permission to your app in settings

Comment: This works inside the Android studio virtual device, but not in a mobile phone (Vivo)

Comment: i told you for devices like vivo,oppo, redmi you have to turn on auto start in settings. These chinese custom skins don't give auto start by default. Mark this answer as correct also

Comment: Thanks Hritik. It is working after enabling auto start by default for the app :)

Comment: Just to mention, the code is now working without having the service. Autostart resolved the issue